# Java ByteArrayInputStream in C# using iTextSharp XMLWorker

Tags: c#, css, itext, xmlworker, bytearrayinputstream

I am using **ITextSharp** and I wanted to **include CSS to my PDF**. Below is my current code:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlSource.toString().getBytes());  
ByteArrayInputStream cis = new ByteArrayInputStream(cssSource.toString().getBytes());
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, bis, cis);
```

But the problem is that I **lack a reference** for `ByteArrayInputStream`. Even `System.IO` cannot fix the error. Are there any other workarounds to this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: That code looks like Java version of iText. Are you sure u need help with C#? If so, can you post your C# code?

Comment: If you try to port java samples to .Net, `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` usually become `MemoryStream`.

Comment: @MikeHixson I need help on converting it to **C#** but I'm new to IText. My current code uses `parseXHtml` but does not have the CSS parameter but I realized that I **need** to include CSS in my PDF. The code above is the only snippet that I saw online that incorporates CSS and HTML using `parseXHtml`.

Comment: @mkl Hi, could you help me on converting the `ByteArrayInputStream` code above into C# including the **Memory Stream**?

Answer (score 0):

A simple, working example to get you started:

```
var html = "<h1>H1</h1>";
var css = "h1 {font-size: 2em;}";

using (var htmlStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html)))
{
    using (var cssStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(css)))
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var document = new Document())
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(
                    document, memoryStream
                );
                document.Open();
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
                    writer, document, htmlStream, cssStream
                );
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(OUTPUT_FILE, memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```